# Is it a good idea to use varchar(max) as a stored procedure argument?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that takes a string of a pipe delimited array of IDs and parses them out. I want to have this happen in a transaction, so don't want to pass them in one at a time.

If I use varchar(max) as to not limit the size of the argument passed in, will this cause problems? I don't see the limit being hit, but I also don't want to guess or place an arbitrary limit on the string.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc
    @IDs varchar(max) 
AS

BEGIN
  ...
END
GO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not much to it. `varchar(max)` behaves just like any varchar less than 8000 characters until you go above 8000 characters. There should be little to no difference between `varchar(200)` and `varchar(max)` if the actual data is less than 8000 characters. If you're expecting smaller inputs but can't rule out bigger inputs, a `varchar(max)` is great.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it would cause problems but I prefer to pass what amount to multi-element 'arrays' in to sprocs using XML. It makes it clearer what kind of data it is and there are nice SQL-XML tools to 'transform' the XML into a pseudo-table you can join against. Then, the translation from pipe-delimited -> XML can happen outside the DB.

Comment: if it is a simple list of values (not multi-valued) XML adds a lot of extra data (all the tags) to transmit.

Comment: I've seen other suggestions about using XML for exactly this purpose, but I'll add that using `varchar(MAX)` definitely won't cause problems in-and-of-itself. There still is an 'arbitrary' limit (2147483647 characters according to SQL Server Books Online [for SQL Server 2005]), but it is as @KM says "practically unlimited".

Comment: Yeah I am leary of using XML for a single list of values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on SQL Server 2008, then I'd use a table valued parameter.  If not, I always prefer to use the smallest size possible, but I don't see why MAX would cause any problems as a stored procedure parameter.  If you want the parameter to be practically unlimited in length than go for MAX.

Answer (score 0):

I use varchar(max) when I don't know the limit(thats what its there for).  Always good to set the variables with a certain length, but if unknown this is acceptable, and won't cause any problems, except for your database growing a bit larger, and people able to dupe larger amount of data in

Answer (score 0):

TSQL isn't a good string manipulation language, and performance-wise (and code wise!) you'd be better off parsing the string outside of the DB - so +1 to [n8wrl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721694/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-varcharmax-as-a-stored-procedure-argument/3721712#3721712).  Intrinsically though, there's nothing wrong with using a `varchar(max)` for this.

Aside from using XML like n8wrl suggested, a [Table Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) might be a good option if you're using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I want to wrap the processing in a transaction, so that means I don't want to parse it outside the DB.